# every time i try to open a project in pycharm python 2.7 i get an error "Failed to create a virtual environment"

Tags: python, python-2.7, pycharm

Every time I try to open a project in pycharm python 2.7  I get an error "Failed to create a virtual environment" but when i open python3.10 i have no issues.

Unfortunately I need to use the older version for a specific project.
I read that you can delete the newer version from the computer, but I'm afraid it will delete other projects I wrote...

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lkwyY.png)

I would be happy to help :)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please edit the question to include the choices you make in the [Create new Project Dialogue](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/creating-and-running-your-first-python-project.html#creating-simple-project) if you don't choose New enviorment or create it outside the IDE it should work.

Comment: Is there a specific reason for using the obsolete version 2 of Python?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Could you describe in the question what it is in the image? (Please do no link images in a question. And if you have an error: please copy the text. How did you create the new project? Maybe just there is no more the needed dependencies online.

Comment: Send `idea.log` from **Help | Show Log in ...** to PyCharm support at pycharm-support@jetbrains.com after reproducing the problem. The exact error should be mentioned in the log. PyCharm 2022.3 will report more descriptive error messages (https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-53394/Non-descriptive-error-creating-virtual-environments).